# Taking square roots in inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

I ran into a small problem while taking the square root on both sides of an inequality.
Suppose it is given that $(x+1)^2 < 4$.

Then, after taking the square root of both sides, $-2 < x+1 < 2$ and hence $-1 < x < 1$.

But on further analysis it appears that the solution of $x$ where $x$ ranges from $-3$ to $1$ is not obtained.

I know that I can expand $(x+1)^2$, subtract $4$, and then use wavy curve method (i.e., the *method of intervals*) to get the complete solution.

However my confusion lies in why the solutions have not been obtained by taking the square root on both sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpret this inequation in terms of *distance*:
$$(x+1)^2<4\iff\sqrt{(x+1)^2}=\lvert x+1\rvert<2.$$
Now $\lvert x+1\rvert$ is the distance betwen $x$ and $-1$, so
$$\lvert x+1\rvert<2\iff -1-2<x<-1+2.$$

Comment: @Sriram Cummaragunta: Why do you want to obtain $x$ between $-1$ and $+1$?

Comment: Never mind I got it.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're doing nothing wrong involving square roots; your problem is with subtraction.  You are correct that $(x+1)^2<4$ is equivalent to $$-2<x+1<2.$$  However, it is not correct to then conclude that $-1<x<1$.  Rather, you must subtract $1$ from each part of the inequality, giving $$-2-1<(x+1)-1<2-1$$ or $$-3<x<1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that taking square roots gives you two alternative answers with same absolutes but different signs. Generally, if taking square root, we take only the positive root. Here,

$$(x+1)^2<4$$

$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2}<\sqrt4$$

$$x+1<2$$

$$AND$$

$$-x-1<-2$$

Comment: In the OR part the inequality evaluates to x>1 which does not satisfy the original condition.Perhaps that was an error?

Comment: @Sriram Cummaragunta See, that's what I'm saying. You almost always take the positive square root, hence the solution for the negative is mostly not given.

Comment: @MalayThe Dynamo: I think it should be *AND*, not *OR*.

Comment: @Bernard Yes. Thanks.